# Controlling javascript with checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I'm building a chrome extension where i want to control javascript with this checkbox :

```
    <div class="modal-icons">
        <div class="flex-container">
            <div class="flex">
                <label class="switch">
                  <input id="check" type="checkbox" checked>
                  <span class="slider round"></span>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

How can i get the state in the .js file?

I have tried :

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
const checked = document.getElementById('check').checked;
  # ACTION 
  });
```

and

```
var checked = document.getElementById('check').checked;
console.log('checked');
```

And also similar approaches but I'm not sure how to get the state.

I get the error message : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of null

Can I write this for instance?

```
if (checked == true) {
   console.log('checked');
}
```

Or will it give a value of 'checked'?

Could someone help me to explain this, please?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with

```js
var checked = document.getElementById('check').checked;
console.log('checked');
```

is that the variable checked stays one value and is never updated, i.e if the checkbox is checked by default, checked is always `true` even if it is changed. In addition, there is nothing which listens for updates to the checkbox.

I would bind an event listener to the element

```js
document.getElementById('check').addEventListener("change", event => {
    if(event.target.checked) {
        // Checkbox is checked
    } else {
        // Checkbox is not checked
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally this solved my problem :

```
document.getElementById('check').addEventListener('change', func => {
if (event.target.checked) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    file: 'safe.js'
    }); 
    }
});
```

I only managed to run a script from a different file though.

Also the script file executing this code had to be named 'popup.js' and did not work with other names - even if declared in the manifest file corretly.

I think it has to do with some special requisites of Chrome extensions.